# How do I prepopulate the value of a taxonomy term reference field on the node creation form?

Tags: hooks, entities

I'm using an approach similar to the one taken in [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/10496/5147).  The difference is that I have a taxonomy term reference field in the user profile that I want to use to prepopulate a custom content type.

To prepopulate a text field on a custom content type with a value from the user profile, I have added this code to a custom module:

```
function MYMODULE_form_MYFORM_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 // test if node for has been assigned a NID. If not then populate fields with default data */
  if (empty($form['nid']['#value']) && (!isset($form['#node']->op))){
    global $user;
    $user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
    //set age
    if (isset($user_fields->field_acc_age['und'][0]['value'])){

      $form['field_ad_age']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] =  $user_fields->field_acc_age['und'][0]['value'];
    }
```

However, when attempting to prepopulate a taxonomy term reference field from the user profile to the custom content type, the above code doesn't work; there is no error, but the value is not carried across.  I assume this is because term references are stored differently in the DB, but I don't understand how to change the code to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
function MYMODULE_form_MYFORM_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Check if the node has a node ID. If not, then populate the fields with the default data.
  if (empty($form['nid']['#value']) && (!isset($form['#node']->op))) {
    global $user;
    $user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
    // Set age.
    if (isset($user_fields->field_acc_age['und'][0]['tid'])) {
      $form['field_ad_age']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $user_fields->field_acc_age['und'][0]['tid'];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `$user_fields->field_acc_age['und'][0]['tid'];` would set form field value to numeric tid instead of term name. How to make it set to term name just like it worked when we set manually filling form?