# Is there a way to add content templates for blog

Tags: 7

I've been asked to add templates (where a blog post is pre-created with certain content) and the user simply selects it and make minor changes. Please note this is not a visual template, but a content one.

Thanks!

Comment: if you are asking about the content type then, make node tpl for that content type.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Manage fields

Ex: `/admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields`

Then **click on edit**, for example, the body field. Look for **Default Value** and put whatever you want there.

Now when a user tries to add a new article, it will have the body pre-filled-out and they can change it if they wish.

Comment: Would it be possible to have more than one? For instance, a template for each occasion?

Comment: you would then need to create a content type for each occasion.

Answer (score 0):

You can theme template by content type. You need to create a node--blog.tpl.php
and write your code in here. Check out this link for more info.

https://www.drupal.org/node/17565

Comment: Thanks mate, but that's not what I meant. What I want is, when the user adds a new blog post for instance, when the user hits create content, the blog will be pre-populated with some content and the user will only update this content. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok. I suggest you may use the hook_form_alter then for your content type form and prepopulate the fields based on the logged in userid or from his profile fields. You may refer this answer [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10496/how-to-pre-populate-fields-on-a-node-creation-form-based-on-fields-from-profile2)

Comment: That'd roughly what I'm looking for but I'd prefer something that the user can edit the templates (no code knowledge required sort of thing)